# What is the difference between IBM NL Classifier and NLU custom model classification?

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, text-classification

What is the difference between IBM NL Classifier and NLU custom model classification?

NL Classifier is trained on text (probably short text)
and when checking NLU custom model, it can also be trained on custom data for classification.

Anyone know what the differences are? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use NLC to train up a corpus that is able to recognise intent.

NLU makes use of a lexicon based corpus to pull out information like language semantics and identify entities, keywords, concepts and so on.

Comment: thanks. does it mean NLC is more suitable for intent?
and NLU also offers classification, and good for news/articles?